# How to get $modalInstance?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to use the same controller for adding and editing item as well in normal view and in modal (ui.bootstrap).

In that controller I've got item data injected (if it's adding then it's null):

```
function itemCtrl($scope, itemData) {
    $scope.afterSumbit = function() {
        //If it's opened in modal I have to pass new item values to modal opener
        //but I don't have $modalInstance
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I opend ctrl in modal I have to resolve modal but I don't have `$modalInstance`, because it wasn't injected.
I can't add `$modalInstance` as depency to controller because in normal view I'm not using it.

I know if controller was opened be modal, but how to inject `$modalInstance`?

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: does not `$modal.open` return an instance?

Comment: can you make a simple demo that demonstrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have to close modal after submiting form - that is from controller, which uses $modalInstance. $modal.open inastance is for handling closed modal result

Comment: you can use the return value of `$modal.open` to close the modal

Comment: I did it with emiting event to closeModal. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

try to set the scope of the modal window to the current scope like

```
app.controller(......
var modalInstance = null;
$scope.openModal = function (size) {
modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModal.html',
            size: size,
            windowClass: 'medium-size-modal',
            scope: $scope
        });
        return modalInstance;
    };
```

later you can dismiss it from dismiss/cancel/ok method by using the instance you created like so

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
        if (modalInstance) {
            modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
    };
```